# setOnClickListener not getting triggered on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to trigger an OnClick event from the `ConstraintLayout` defined in xml. But surprisingly it is not getting triggered. Other similar layouts are working and it is exactly the same as others.

Here is the code:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_plan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/plan_txt_subtitle">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_plan_name"
                    style="@style/grocery_item_subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/star_icon"
                    tools:text="  Sparkle Plan" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_upgrade_plan"
                    style="@style/mini_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_plan_name"
                    tools:text="@string/upgrade_plan_description" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/divider_line_0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_upgrade_plan" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
binding.clPlan.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    if (!preferences.isPaidUser())
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_accountFragment_to_upgradePlanFragment)
}
```

I am using data binding and have set it up properly. Other similar layouts with same case working fine, only issue with this one.
When I tried to set onclicklistener on `TextView` `txt_plan_name` inside it, it works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` from the text views – they might be intercepting with click listener or may be log or add a toast to check if a click has been registered or not.

```
binding.clPlan.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if (!preferences.isPaidUser())
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_accountFragment_to_upgradePlanFragment)
    }
})
```